# Выводит Call to a member function on null

Tags: php, sqlite3

возникла проблема.
Нужно получить информацию из базы даннвх sqlite3, но почему-то выводит ошибку, указывает на саму функцию получения, может я ее как-то ннправильно написал? Если не сложно, посмотрите, код ниже

```
public function getValue(string $value, $player){
    $p = strtolower($player);
    $result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM money WHERE playerName = '$p';");
     $r = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);
    if($r == false)
        return false;
    foreach($r as $val => $res)
    return $res;
 }
```

Comment: почему `return` в цикле?

Comment: @DrMcSheen я думаю он просто хотел достать первый элемент из результата запроса, но это не точно :)

Comment: а по-вопросу, судя по модификатору доступа - это метод, а значит смею предположить, что Вы просто не инициализировали объект с этим методом, если судить по тексту ошибки. Что я имею ввиду - Вы делаете вот такое по-факту: `null->getValue($value, $player);`. Надеюсь Вы поняли что я имею ввиду ;)